# Understanding the Runge pheonomena and Chebyshev nodes.

Tags: numerical-methods

I am studying the [Runge's phenomenon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%27s_phenomenon) and there are a couple things I would like to understand better.

Suppose we interpolate the Runge's function with use equally spaced nodes to interpolate the function on the interval $[-1,1]$.

From what I understand the main reason the interpolation error grows with more nodes is because the value of $f^{n+1}(\xi)$ (where $f$ is the Runge function)  grows really fast with $n$. Also, I believe that the reason because the error is higher in the extremes of the interval $[-1,1]$ is because of $w(x)=\prod_{i=0}^{n}(x-x_i)$.

Is this correct?

Furthermore, why do Chebyshev nodes interpolate the Runge function way better?